# Loading Lots of Data into MySQL too Slow

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm running MySQL on my local computer. I've setup a database with multiple tables, 3 of which are potentially interesting here:

```
CREATE TABLE rnames (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    rname varchar(16) UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE fetch_times (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp BIGINT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE measurements (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    rname_id INT,
    coorx real,
    coory real,
    timestamp BIGINT,
    delay integer,
    fetch_id integer,
    UNIQUE (rname_id, coorx, coory, timestamp),
    FOREIGN KEY (rname_id) REFERENCES rnames(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fetch_id) REFERENCES fetch_times(id)
);
```

`rnames` and `fetch_times` have 397 and 2 rows respectively, `measurements` starts as an empty table and I want to populate it with ~ 5,000,000 rows. To do that, I created a CSV file with all those rows.

Example line from the CSV file

```
\N,143,14.61944,50.08065,1595053203,-13,\N
```

Then I ran

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE measurements FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

That's taking too long. What's really interesting is that the insertion speed dramatically drops as the table gets larger. I've made some measurements of how long the `LOAD DATA` takes given the number of rows in the CSV file.

```
#rows   total execution time (s)
1k      0.08
2k      0.17
5k      0.39
10k     0.68
20k     0.84
50k     1.24
100k    2.00
200k    4.14
500k    22.14
1.0M    55.00
2.0M    129.71
2.1M    130.75
2.2M    163.15
2.3M    186.63
2.4M    206.74
2.5M    247.74
2.6M    264.47
2.7M    321.06
2.8M    374.64
2.9M    456.19
3.0M    524.02
3.1M    664.80
3.2M    746.19
3.3M    918.73
```

[image: graph of the data directly above]

Note that I always ran `TRUNCATE measurements;` to empty the table before each of those measurements and each measurement used a new random permutation of the CSV file.

Q: Why do we have that sharp increase in the execution time?

I would understand that the time to insert one more row grows with `log` of the size of the table. That would yield approximately `n log(n)` time for inserting `n` rows into a table that starts empty. The above data and graph however show a considerably faster time increase, I think.

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

I can provide any other necessary data.

Many thanks for any help!

**EDIT 2020/07/27 15:19 UTC**

As the majority of comments seemed to suggest, I created a new database with only one table -- the `measurements` table, which then looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    rname_id INT,
    coorx real,
    coory real,
    timestamp BIGINT,
    delay integer,
    fetch_id integer
);
```

i.e. I removed the `UNIQUE` and `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

I ran the same experiment again, getting much higher insertion speeds especially when the table was already getting large.

```
#rows   total execution time, without constraints (s)
1k      0.05
2k      0.10
5k      0.22
10k     0.52
20k     0.58
50k     0.84
100k    1.20
200k    2.04
500k    4.38
1.0M    9.91
2.0M    34.40
2.1M    21.48
2.2M    39.52
2.3M    42.54
2.4M    22.72
2.5M    46.58
2.6M    48.33
2.7M    31.19
2.8M    52.15
2.9M    56.70
3.0M    58.10
3.1M    60.29
```

[image: graph of the data above (execution time for table with removed constraints)]

This way, I'm able to add my 5 million rows into the table in ~ 40 s. Then I can add the `UNIQUE` and `FOREIGN KEY` constraints. That itself took ~ 40 s for `UNIQUE` and ~ 160 s and ~ 110 s for both the `FOREIGN KEY`s. The overall time to create and populate the table as I wanted it is therefore a bit under 6 min. -- much more acceptable than time that was needed before.

Thanks for the suggestion!

The problem itself is solved and I get that inserting to a table is faster when there are fewer constraints. However, I'm still not sure why the insertion time starts growing as rapidly as the first experiment showed since the time to insert a row show should only grow with the `log` of the table size.

**EDIT 2020/07/28 20:02 UTC**

reacting to Rick James' answer

I have 16 GB of RAM on my laptop on which I run the database now.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728` (128 MB, i.e. the MySQL default) until now; I tried increasing that -- see below.

The full `measurements` table with all the ~ 5M rows and the constraints I wanted it to have reports `301760512` (~ 288 MB) for `Data_length`.

I set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 2 GB. I tried inserting 2.5M and 3.0M rows into the table with the constraints before and after this change.

```
2.5M rows before    136.06 s
2.5M rows after     132.64 s
3.0M rows before    458.69 s
3.0M rows after     206.99 s
```

While there is almost no change for only 2.5M rows, the reduction of execution time for 3.0M rows is pretty large. From that I guess that increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` makes the execution time grow much less dramatically with the number of rows.

I might try diving up the rows to load into smaller chunks in future, but this seems good enough for now.

Comment: Tried disabling/removing foreign keys and unique index while inserting? The more data the more time it takes to check constraints.

Comment: An interesting question- but maybe better suited to the dba forum?

Comment: Are there any other indexes defined on the measurement table? You could drop the indexes before doing the import, then create them after it is complete. That way, the index is not being processed after each insert.

Comment: @Bryn there are no other indexes

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I will probably try that then. But I thought that still it should not make the time grow that fast.

Comment: @mimo31 try SET foreign_key_checks = 0; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE measurements FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

Comment: then post results

Comment: Can't you split the file? That Big transactions needs a lot resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**

How much RAM do you have?
What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?
How big (in gigabytes) is the table?  (`SHOW TABLE STATUS`)?

The fact the curve is not linear makes me suspect that it is becoming I/O bound.

Another thing to try is to load it in chunks of, say, 10K rows at a time.  The reason for this is that a lot of effort goes into preserving the previous state of the table in order to recover in case of a rollback or crash.

**Speed ups**

Get rid of `fetch_times`.  `INT` is 4 bytes; `TIMESTAMP` is 5 bytes.  There is virtually no space saved by normalizing the timestamp, and there is a lot of overhead in maintaining that extra table.

In general, do not normalize "continuous" values -- such as datetime, timestamp, float, etc.  `SELECTing` on a normalized range can be terrible for performance.

`UNIQUE (rname_id, coorx, coory, timestamp),` -- It is often unwise to have floats and times in a `UNIQUE` index; you risk a uniqueness error because two things happen to occur in the same second, etc.

Assuming you are I/O-bound, shrinking the table will help:

`REAL`, I think, means `DOUBLE`, which takes 8 bytes.  `FLOAT` takes only 4 bytes (8 bytes for the lat/lng).  Sailing off the cost of Yemen?  `FLOAT` gives a resolution of 1.7m / 5.6 feet.  `DECIMAL(8,6)/(9,6)` gives 16cm / 6 inch resolution in only 1 byte more (9 bytes for the pair).  `DECIMAL(8,5)/(9,5)` matches your input but also take 9 bytes.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices

`INTEGER` is the same as `INT`; they take 4 bytes.  Consider `MEDIUMINT` - 3 bytes and range of +/-8M.  See also `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`, `SMALLINT`, etc.

**Unnormalize**

In order to get rid of fetch_id, you would need to load the CSV into a temporary table, then do a second step to copy the rows into the 'real' table.  The load could be very fast because it would not need secondary indexes or FKs.  Chunking, in this step, would probably not be necessary.

The second step is to do a `INSERT ... SELECT` with `JOIN fetchtimes` to move the data into the main table.  Chunking might be necessary, and easy to do if the temp table has an auto_increment PK.

Comment: "I/O bound" means that disk I/O becomes the bottleneck, right? And that happens because for a large number of rows, the table does no longer fit into the innodb buffer pool in RAM and MySQL has to put some things on the disk?

Comment: normalization of the fetch time for the ```measurements``` table is not main purpose of the ```fetch_times``` table. I need it for keeping track of the times I made a fetch independently of the measurements. E.g. there might be a row in ```fetch_times``` with no associated row in ```measurements```

Comment: the rationale behind having the floats and the time in the ```UNIQUE``` is that I'm fetching some data from a server and I need to know whether the new data it's sending me are the same as some it's already sent me before. The floats are guaranteed to be exactly the same if it's the same data

Comment: I am planning to optimize the datatypes at some point as you suggest; they're now what they're because I'm mainly just prototyping now. Thank you for a helpful answer!

Comment: @mimo31 - I/O-bound is a disk bottleneck.  But that could be for swapping, for reading/writing data from/to tables from/to the buffer_pool, etc.